# How to write regular expression in JMeter for CSRF token?

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to write regular expression in JMeter regular extractor for CSRF Token:

```
CSRF Token: P_rF1DbLR4JWcBtxEwGKKw==
```

and Expression I am using is:

```
name : CSRF_Token_Retrieved_Value
regular expression: x-csrf-token:\s+(.+)
template : $1$
```

I get this error

> CSRF token validation failed

in next steps.

Comment: May be you can try checking the regular expression used from the previous response using the View Result Tree > [Regular expression tester](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree).

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression doesn't match the value you provided, you need to change it to:

```
CSRF Token:\s+(.+)
```

Demo:

[image]

Also if the token comes in one of the [HTTP response headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) you need to switch the Regular Expression Extractor to look into `Response Headers`:

[image]

More information: [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites)