# How to log in HTTPS resource using JMeter test script recorder saving X-XSRF-TOKEN?

Tags: https, jmeter, x-xsrf-token

I am trying to record a scenario in JMeter which will able me to login in application and perform some actions, but I am stuck in the logon stage when I am trying to reproduce the recorded scenario. I had set an a proxy in a browser, set a root JMeter certificate and JMeter records everything.

In the login I am performing POST request like this:

`POST https://ip:port/api/logon`

POST data:
{"user":"text","member":"text","password":"text"}

Cookie data:
JSESSIONID=node{random}.node{random}

But it fails with `response code 400 (Bad request)`.

I believe that I should capture X-XSRF-TOKEN and use it to be able to access session in a right way, but I can not do it. I am trying before this request to capture the X-XSRF-TOKEN into ${token} variable using JMeter's regular expression extractor. I can see it in the "response headers", but still can not find a way to capture it to be able to log in this resource.

How to log in HTTPS resource using JMeter test script recorder saving X-XSRF-TOKEN?

**Update:**
I figured out how to get an a XSRF-TOKEN from the response header, using regexp. It is in this format: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie
Also I've used info from this article: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites

To get it I am using JMeter's Regular Expression Extractor, where:

`Field to check: Response-Headers`

`Regular expression: Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=([^;]+?)`
I find out that JMeter's regexp parser probably greedy and reverse.

`Template: $1$`

`Match No.: 1`

`Default Value: NOT_FOUND`

After that I am giving ${XSRF_TOKEN} to the X-XSRF-TOKEN field in HTTP Header manager for the next HTTP requests, but when I am starting the scripts, it still won't work and sends me a new X-XSRF-TOKEN in response header.

**Update №2:**

I find out that jmeter do not send all cookies required by opening developer console in the Chrome Browser -> Network [Record].
It sends JSESSIONID cookie, but not XSRF_TOKEN cookie. Now I am struggling with adding this cookie to my request for it to be able to estabilish a session.
Seems that just adding it in a HTTP Cookie Manager like:

`Name: XSRF-TOKEN`  `Value: ${XSRF_TOKEN}`  `Domain: XXX`  `Path: /`  `Secure: yes\no`

won't work because variable value not assigning and it just shows me ${XSRF_TOKEN} in the cookie send request.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to find a response for my question.
It strongly resembles
[How to write regular expression in JMeter for CSRF token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61877968/how-to-write-regular-expression-in-jmeter-for-csrf-token)
but I used
`Regular-expression: XSRF-TOKEN=([^;]+?)`
and then I am setting cookie in HTTP Header like:
Seems that just adding it in a HTTP Cookie Manager like:
`Name: XSRF-TOKEN`  `Value: ${XSRF_TOKEN}`  `Domain: XXX`  `Path: /`  `Secure: yes\no`